# Getting a sql Error, db2 function error return result

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-function

My Function is getting a error but I don't know why ...

***MY (DB2)SQL CODE:***

```
CREATE FUNCTION gibX(sseries INTEGER, idd INTEGER) RETURNS Double
 BEGIN
   Declare result Double;
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY m.x ASC) AS Row, m.x  INTO result 
   FROM messungen m WHERE m.series=sseries and Row=idd;
   return result;
 END;
```

***ERROR:***

```
CREATE FUNCTION;
   return result;
;, DRIVER=4.13.80
```

... and passed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference `row` in the `where`.  One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT x INTO result
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.x ASC) AS Row, m.x  
      FROM messungen m
      WHERE m.series = sseries
     ) m
WHERE Row = idd;
```